# How can I remove the event handler once the click event has fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `click` event I wired up on a `div` on my page.

Once the `click` event has fired, I want to unbind the event on that `div`.

How can I do this? Can I unbind it in the `click` event handler itself?

Answer (score 14):

Use the "[one](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one#typedatafn)" function:

```
$("#only_once").one("click", function() {
alert('this only happens once');
});
```

Comment: Wow. That's actually one of the cooler things I've seen from jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the jQuery documentation found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind):

```
 $("#unbind").click(function () {
      $("#theone").unbind('click', aClick)
                  .text("Does nothing...");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In plain JavaScript:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

myDiv.addEventListener('click', clicked, false);

function clicked()
{
    // Process event here...

    myDiv.removeEventListener('click', clicked, false);
}
```

Steve

Answer (score 0):

There's the unbind function documented here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind

Fits your example :)