# How to make the button can click once?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove the event handler once the click event has fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740794/how-can-i-remove-the-event-handler-once-the-click-event-has-fired)

I am trying to assign click event to a button using live and want the user can only trigger it only once. Are there anyways to do it?

```
//I only want the alert show once and disable the click event... 
$('#testBtn').live('click', function(){
    alert('hey ya');
})
```

**Please note:** The button is created dynamically.

Comment: look at this http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Please update your question to clearly show that you are using live because the element is dynamically created.

Comment: I've gathered test cases here for you on which is fastest - http://jsperf.com/one-event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `one()` with delegated handlers as well (in jQuery 1.7+) and replace the deprecated `live()` function with something like this:

```
$(document).one('click', '#testBtn', function(){
    alert('hey ya');
});
```

replace `document` with the closest non-dynamic parent.

Comment: +1 this is correct way to do this. This will work for dynamically created elements (my answer won't work in this case) and, as it seems, this is what @Rouge wanted to achive.

Comment: Thanks +1. what if the testBtn is a class. It doesn't seem to work if I use class inside the one function

Comment: Well this uses id selector (`#`), just replace it with class selector (`.`): `.testBtn`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function:

```
$('#testBtn').one('click', function(){
    alert('hey ya');
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SEjYK/

Comment: And with a dynamic element, it would work exactly like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SEjYK/1/), not at all ?

Comment: I can't use .one because I have .live method. Any ways around this?

Comment: @Rouge - see my answer below!

Comment: @adeneo - Can you quote where in the question he says he requires delegation, or uses dynamic elements.  My eyes mustn't be what they used to be because I for the life of me can't find it!

Comment: I think it's pretty much implied by using live()

Comment: @adeneo - Ah okay, thanks.  I wasn't attempting to 2nd guess the questioner.  I would have asked him first, rather than ass u me.

Comment: He's now confirmed it above - well done.  Bad questioner X(

Comment: @Rouge this can be easily done, check adeneo answer

Comment: Uhm, well, the question is to replace `live()` with something that fires only once, and that would be the delegated version of `one()`. It could be `live()` is not needed, but the question does seem very clear non the less?

Comment: @adeneo Like I said, it was an assumption.  It's obviously always better to deal with facts, so asking would be better.  But you were right this time :)  Anyway, let's not turn this into a conversation.

Comment: @Archer - Does'nt look like I was right. Got three downvotes while this answer keeps getting upvoted.

Comment: @adeneo this is probably due to lots of comments under this answer ;) anyways I've upvoted and commented your answer to encourage people to upvote it, because it seems that it is correct answer for this question.

Comment: @des - thank you. It's funny how many comments or just answering within a few seconds even if the answer is completely unrelated (not saying this is, just see it all the time on SO) can get you upvotes. Seems some people just upvote without reading ?

Comment: Hard to say. I've seen many things here including downvoting all answers for question with no apparent reason (and all were correct if I remember).

Answer (score 0):

use `one()`:

```
$('#testBtn').one('click', function(){
    alert('hey ya');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#testBtn').one('click', function() {
    alert('hey ya');
});
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: If you absolutely want to use 'live':

```
$('#testBtn').live('click', function() {
    $(this).die('click');
    alert('hey ya');
});
```

If you want to use 'one' just run the first code snippet after you've generated the dynamic object and appended it to the document.

If you're using the "live" type approach though I'd recommend using "on" since live is deprecated:

```
$(document).on('click', '#testBtn', function() {
    $(this).die('click');
    alert('hey ya');
});
```

Comment: I have .live and the testBtn is dynamically generated...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way which probably runs the fastest.. going to check with jsperf.com

```
$('#testBtn').bind('click', function() {
       $(this).unbind('click');
       alert('Clicked and unbound!');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/usZSU/

EDIT: I'm thinking this runs the fastest added 3 test cases - http://jsperf.com/one-event
run 2-3 times to get best results.. everytime i run it bind is fastest and one is 3% slower.

Comment: Does'nt matter how fast it is if it does'nt work with dynamic elements ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? all you would have to do is change bind to live you can still unbind an event. Also I would just use plain vanilla JavaScript and addEventListener("click") if you're looking to be dynamic and fast. live and die run the slowest out of the test cases.

Comment: Well, Duh, you're comparing apples and oranges! You're comparing your answer with `bind()`, that won't work with dynamic elements at all, to the delegated version of `one()` and `live()`! Of course the delegated handlers will be slower, but that's not really an issue when the faster `bind()` method won't work with the dynamic element at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are much more sensible answers on this page already, but if you insist on using `.live()` instead of `one()` then this will do what you ask...

```
//I only want the alert show once and disable the click event... 
$('#testBtn').live('click', function(){
    $(this).die('click');
    alert('hey ya');
});
```

`.die('click')` will remove the click event handler, so it will not fire again.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use .one instead of live for the button. That makes more sense..
If you do not want to use it then you can use a Hiddenfield in your page and when the click event is triggered then set the flag value..

Next time when you click the button check for the flag value, if it was already executed once then do not run the code inside it..

Check this example  http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Fakb5/

Also note that .live is deprecated in the current jQuery version. It is preferred to use .on() instead

Answer (score -1):

you can use unbind to remove all click events:

```
 $('#testBtn').unbind('click');
 $('#testBtn').unbind('live');
```

Comment: This wont work for handlers attached via `live()`; you want `die()` for that.